# Issue while creating SparkSession object using SparkConf

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and need some guidance on the below issue -
Whenever I am trying to create a SparkSession object using a SparkConf object I am getting the below error -

> AttributeError: 'SparkConf' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

I am using Spark 2.3 with Python 3.7 in local mode .

```
sconf=SparkConf.setAppName("test")
ss=SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sconf).getOrCreate()
```

I have read some of the solutions available in internet but none of them has resolved my issue .

Even when I am trying to create the SparkSession object directly i.e. without explicit SparkConf object , then also I am getting the same error -

```
ss=SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()

AttributeError: 'SparkConf' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Comment: Which ver of pyspark?

Comment: The version is 2.3

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You might be missing the bracket 
    `sconf=SparkConf().setAppName("test")`
If it doesnt work i tried the below in local which worked

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf
sconf=SparkConf().setAppName("test")
ss=SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sconf).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: The parenthesis for instanciation of SparkConf() are indeed missing.
But adding them doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 4):

**Do not create a new SparkConf() object** : it will be a python object, apparently not compatible with the non-python parts of Spark (it doesn't have the mandatory _get_object_id() method, as expressed by the error message).

The config() method from the builder is cumulative, so you should do :

```
ss = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .config("some.parameter", "some.value") \
    .config("some.other.parameter", "some.other.value") \ 
       etc...
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: It is even stated in the documentation that passing a new SparkConf()-object is valid, so this is not helpful (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession)

Comment: yea the documentation and much code out there appear to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can define configuration like this -

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.app.name', 'Spark Test')])

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: I used the below and it worked for me -conf=SparkConf().setAll([("spark.app.master","local"),("spark.appName","Test")])